# Use Strcpy_s to Copy Dynamically Allocated Char Array

Tags: c++

I'm simply trying to copy what is in 'temp' into 'p' but the program crashes on the strcopy_s line. Am I missing some important rule?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char temp[100] = "Coolbeans";
    int len = strlen(temp);
    char* p = new char[len+1];
    strcpy_s(p, len, temp);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        cout << p[i] << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        cout << temp[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: The important rule you're missing is *use `std::string`*. The length you pass to `strcpy_s` should be `len + 1`, not `len`.

Comment: and also, prefer `strcpy` and `memcpy` to `strcpy_s`.

Comment: Thanks. adding len+1 fixed the problem. (:

Answer (score 1):

Praetorian hit it on the head. "The important rule you're missing is use `std::string`". Old C functions like `strcpy_s` are notoriously incredibly unreliable and that's the whole point of not doing it anymore. So don't do it. Use `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

The above code snippet result in "Debug Assertion failed" run time error.

```
 strcpy_s(p, len, temp); //Expression:(L"Buffer is too small" &&0)
```

So the answer is strcpy_s(p, len+1, temp); will work fine in your case.

Comment: It's just that if he tries to write more string-handling functions, he'll just cock them up over and over again, and even if he succeeds, they'll be unreadable and unmaintainable. Not a useful answer.